# Different AIC results using base R (step/add1/drop1) in oppose to broom:: glance

Tags: r, broom

I am reading this short paper:

[https://pages.pomona.edu/~jsh04747/courses/math158/multlin4.pdf](https://pages.pomona.edu/%7Ejsh04747/courses/math158/multlin4.pdf))

And following the examples on the mtcars dataset, I get different AIC results when comparing to glance from broom package.

Here is what I am talking about:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df <- mtcars[,c(1,3:7)]
attach(df)
# Using stepwise backward in Base R:
step(lm(mpg~disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec),direction = "backward")
# AIC = 63.89, mpg ~ drat + wt + qsec

# Using glance() from broom:
glance(lm(mpg~disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec))
# AIC = 158
```

I have a feeling I lack some formal theoretical knowledge about the formula but would love to get some help, because these are big differences...

I am aware of stepwise/back/for ward yielding different results depending on who got in the model first*

Comment: `step` uses `extractAIC`, while `glance` (probably) uses `AIC`. See the Details under `extractAIC` for why those two function give different answers.

Comment: Note that these should only differ in absolute value, the differences in AIC (which is what probably matters to you) should be identical.

Comment: Thanks. If they should only differ in absolute values, why is the big difference then? It's a huge difference (63 or 158)

Comment: It's just an additive constant that is different. Again, see `?extractAIC`, under Details: _"For linear models with unknown scale (i.e., for lm and aov), -2 log L is computed from the deviance and uses a different additive constant to logLik and hence AIC."_